# `sorted()` occurs `SyntaxError` in python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I have the following code, which try to sort list with its index in python3:

```
myList = [1,3,4,5,6]
sorted((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(myList))
```

above code work fine. But when I try to reverse the order by

```
sorted((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(myList),reverse=True)
```

I get

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

What is going here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what it says; parenthesize the [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension). This is the generator expression you are trying to sort:

```
(e,i) for i,e in enumerate(myList)
```

When it is the *sole argument*, Python automatically assumes parentheses, but if there is another argument, you must explicitly add parentheses, i.e.

```
sorted(((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(myList)), reverse=True)
```